# Use of ::class method

Tags: php, php-5.1

I'm working on an old application now, and I want to use `::class` method, however, it's not available for PHP version 5.1.

My question is:
What is the equivalent of

```
SomeClass::class
```

in PHP < 5.1

Edit:
It seems there's no alternative method like I mentioned above. For a workaround, I did this:

```
public static $class = __CLASS__;
```

and im calling it like this:
`SomeClass::$class`

Comment: why are you using such an old version of PHP? O.O

Comment: It's not mine. That's why I'm not familiar with the old methods.

Comment: `$class = get_class($this);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I would like too, but it doesn't match the usage I need for my bus pattern.

Comment: PHP 5.1 became unsupported (and thus dangerously insecure to still run) 13 **years** ago. It's more than a decade past time to upgrade.

Comment: The answer to "how can I smash my genitals with a hammer" will be "don't do that". Same applies here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_class()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

```
<?php
class A 
{ 

}

$obj = new A(); 
echo get_class($obj) . PHP_EOL;
```

This outputs :

> A

Comment: I would like to use it also, but it doesn't match the usage I need for my bus pattern. But thanks anyway (y)

Comment: There's a big difference between this and `::class`.  This requires you to pass in an instance while `::class` can be used without instantiating the class so I wouldn't call this an equivalent of `::class`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson indeed, but I don't know other ways to do that in that low version of php